# Generating function for the sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

$$
2, 2\sqrt 2, \sqrt 2 ( \sqrt 2 -1 ); \frac 1 3 \sqrt 2( \sqrt 2 - 1 )(
\sqrt 2 - 2), \frac 1 {3*4} \sqrt 2( \sqrt 2 - 1)(\sqrt 2 - 2)(\sqrt 2 - 3),...
$$
We can derive summation:
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}x^i \frac 2 {i!} \prod_{j=0}^i (\sqrt 2 - j)
$$
$e^x$ expansion is pretty close but I am stuck beyond this.

Comment: What do you want to do with this generating function? Do you want to evaluate it in closed form? Also, where did you find this problem?

Comment: For example, the sequence $1,1,1,...$ can derived from $\frac 1 {1-x}$, that's what I am looking for.

Comment: Ok. Where did you find this problem? And do you have a reason to expect this to be nice?

Comment: This is from school assignment and this shouldn't be too hard, but I have no clue how to solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$S_{n+1} = \frac{\sqrt{2} - n}{n+1}S_n$$
$$S_0 = 2$$

But also note:

$$\binom{x}{n+1} = \frac{x-n}{n+1}\binom{x}{n}$$

Thus we can conclude $S_n = 2\binom{\sqrt{2}}{n}$. Using the generating function for the binomial coefficient we find:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty S_nx^n = 2(x+1)^\sqrt{2}$$

Comment: How did you figure it out?

Comment: Oh it is the expansion of Maclaurin series.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The series expansion implies that, if our function is $f(x)$, then

$$f^{(n)}(0) = 2\prod_{j=0}^i (\sqrt{2}-j).$$

Do you know any functions that have iterated derivatives of this form, a product of terms that decrease by $1$ each time?